# My form is not inserting even tho it produces "success" message

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable

I'm using Ajax + Datatable + Codeigniter. My target is to insert my form into my DB. However, it is not inserting. My current codes produces successful state alert. However, it is not inserting. Is there anything I missed? Additionally, i checked my image file path and it is still empty after insert. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. [image]

[image]

**Views:**

```
<div class="table-responsive">  
                <br/>  
                <button type="button" id="add_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Add</button>  
                <br /><br />  
                <table id="user_datas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">  
                     <thead>  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="10%">Image</th>  
                               <th width="35%">First Name</th>  
                               <th width="35%">Last Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Edit</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Delete</th>  
                          </tr>  
                     </thead>  
                </table>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="userModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <form method="post" id="user_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >  
                <div class="modal-content">  
                     <div class="modal-header">  
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>  
                     </div>  
                     <div class="modal-body">  
                      
                          <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          
                          <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                            
                     
                     
                          <input type="file" name="user_image" id="user_image" />  
                          <span id="user_uploaded_image"></span>  
                     </div>  
                     <div class="modal-footer">  
                          <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="action" id="action" class="btn btn-success" value="Add" />  
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </form>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

**Ajax:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add_button').click(function(){  
           $('#user_form')[0].reset();  
           $('.modal-title').text("Add User");  
           $('#action').val("Add");  
           $('#user_uploaded_image').html('');  
      })  
      var dataTable = $('#user_datas').DataTable({  
           "processing":true,  
           "serverSide":true,  
           "order":[],  
           "ajax":{  
                url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'profile/fetch_user'; ?>",  
                type:"POST"  
           },  
           "columnDefs":[  
                {  
                     "targets":[0, 3, 4],  
                     "orderable":false,  
                },  
           ],  
      });  
      $(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  
           var firstName = $('#firstname').val();  
           var lastName = $('#lastname').val();   
           var extension = $('#user_image').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();  
           if(extension != '')  
           {  
                if(jQuery.inArray(extension, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1)  
                {  
                     alert("Invalid Image File");  
                     $('#user_image').val('');  
                     return false;  
                }  
           }       
     if(firstName != '' && lastName != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'profile/user_action'?>",  
                     method:'POST',  
                     data:new FormData(this),  
                     contentType:false,  
                     processData:false,  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          alert('Successful');  
                          $('#user_form')[0].reset();  
                          $('#userModal').modal('hide');  
                          dataTable.ajax.reload();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                alert("Fields are Required");  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.update', function(){  
           var user_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile/fetch_single_user",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{user_id:user_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     $('#userModal').modal('show');  
                     $('#firstname').val(data.firstname);  
                     $('#lastname').val(data.lastname);  
                     $('.modal-title').text("Edit User");  
                     $('#user_id').val(user_id);  
                     $('#user_uploaded_image').html(data.user_image);  
                     $('#action').val("Edit");  
                }  
           })  
      });  
 });
```

**Controller:**

```
function fetch_user(){
        $this->load->model("profile_repository");
        $fetch_data = $this->profile_repository->make_datatables();
        $data = array();
        foreach($fetch_data as $row)
        {
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = '<img src="'.base_url().'public/assets/upload/'.$row->image.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="35" />';
            $sub_array[] = $row->firstname;
            $sub_array[] = $row->lastname;
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row->userID.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>';
            $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$row->userID.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>';
            $data[] = $sub_array;
        }
        $output = array(
            "draw"                    =>     intval(isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]),
            "recordsTotal"          =>      $this->profile_repository->get_all_data(),
            "recordsFiltered"     =>     $this->profile_repository->get_filtered_data(),
            "data"                    =>     $data
        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    function user_action(){
        if(isset($_POST["action"])  == "Add")
           
        {
            $insert_data = array(
                'firstname'          =>     $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname'               =>     $this->input->post("lastname"),
                'image'                    =>     $this->upload_image()
            );
            $this->load->model('profile_repository');
            $this->profile_repository->insert_crud($insert_data);
            echo 'Data Inserted';
        }
        if(isset($_POST["action"]) == "Edit")
        {
            $user_image = '';
            if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
            {
                $user_image = $this->upload_image();
            }
            else
            {
                $user_image = $this->input->post("hidden_user_image");
            }
            $updated_data = array(
                'firstname'          =>     $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname'               =>     $this->input->post('lastname'),
                'image'                    =>     $user_image
            );
            $this->load->model('profile_repository');
            $this->profile_repository->update_crud($this->input->post("user_id"), $updated_data);
            echo 'Data Updated';
        }
    }
    function upload_image()
    {
        if(isset($_FILES["user_image"]))
        {
            $extension = explode('.', $_FILES['user_image']['name']);
            $new_name = rand() . '.' . $extension[1];
            $destination = './public/assets/upload/' . $new_name;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
            return $new_name;
        }
    }
    function fetch_single_user()
    {
        $output = array();
        $this->load->model("profile_repository");
        $data = $this->profile_repository->fetch_single_user($_POST["user_id"]);
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
            $output['firstname'] = $row->firstname;
            $output['lastname'] = $row->lastname;
            if($row->image != '')
            {
                $output['user_image'] = '<img src="'.base_url().'public/assets/upload/'.$row->image.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="35" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_user_image" value="'.$row->image.'" />';
            }
            else
            {
                $output['user_image'] = '<input type="hidden" name="hidden_user_image" value="" />';
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
var $table = "users";
    var $select_column = array("userID", "firstname", "lastname", "image");
    var $order_column = array(null, "firstname", "lastname", null, null);
    function make_query()
    {
        $this->db->select($this->select_column);
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
        {
            $this->db->like("firstname", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like("lastname", $_POST["search"]["value"]);
        }
        if(isset($_POST["order"]))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->order_by('userID', 'DESC');
        }
    }
    function make_datatables(){
        $this->make_query();

        if(isset($_POST["length"]) && $_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
    function get_filtered_data(){
        $this->make_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    function get_all_data()
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
    function insert_crud($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
    function fetch_single_user($user_id)
    {
        $this->db->where("userID", $user_id);
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result();
    }
    function update_crud($user_id, $data)
    {
        $this->db->where("userID", $user_id);
        $this->db->update("users", $data);
    }  
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake in

`if(isset($_POST["action"])  == "Add")`

isset function returning boolean, therefore your condition will return

`if(true  == "Add")`

which return false.

your code return successful state because it was successful state for your ajax request (code 200), not your insert function

you should change your user_action to :

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    if($_POST["action"] == "Add")
    {
        $insert_data = array(
            'firstname'          =>     $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname'           =>     $this->input->post("lastname"),
            'image'              =>     $this->upload_image()
        );
        $this->load->model('profile_repository');
        $this->profile_repository->insert_crud($insert_data);
        echo 'Data Inserted';
    }
    else if($_POST["action"] == "Edit")
    {
        $user_image = '';
        if($_FILES["user_image"]["name"] != '')
        {
            $user_image = $this->upload_image();
        }
        else
        {
            $user_image = $this->input->post("hidden_user_image");
        }
        $updated_data = array(
            'firstname'          =>     $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname'           =>     $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'image'              =>     $user_image
        );
        $this->load->model('profile_repository');
        $this->profile_repository->update_crud($this->input->post("user_id"), $updated_data);
        echo 'Data Updated';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i did your suggestion. However, it is not inserting. 

https://prnt.sc/10u3550